# Append two lists but got a parse error

Tags: haskell

Hello I am a newbie in Haskell and created this code to append two lists. 
But I will get a parse error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Data.List

-- list a + list b = list c
joinList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
joinList a + b = c
 where 
    a = ["example1","example2","example3"] 
    b = ["example4","example4","example5"]
    c = a ++ b
```

**Error:**

```
test2.hs:5:1: `Parse error in pattern: joinList`
```

Comment: This code does not make much sense. What resource are you using to learn Haskell?

Comment: first I was reading from http://learnyouahaskell.com/ but now I want to create code to learn from it.

Comment: That's a good resource. I recommend reading it a little more closely, trying some of the examples as written, and then modifying those examples to see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make it a "constant" function, one that does not take any arguments, then invoking it (as in the function "main") will perform the computation that you seem to have in mind.

```
joinList :: [a]
joinList = c
 where 
    a = ["example1","example2","example3"] 
    b = ["example4","example4","example5"]
    c = a ++ b

main = print joinList
```

On the other hand, constant functions aren't terribly common. Maybe what you had in mind was a function of two arguments that invokes the append (++).

```
joinList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
joinList a b = c
 where 
    c = a ++ b

main = print $ joinList a b
 where 
    a = ["example1","example2","example3"] 
    b = ["example4","example4","example5"]
```

Of course there are many other possibilities. I hope that these two give you the general idea so that you can arrive where you wanted to go.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is pretty simple. In Haskell, function declarations look like this:

```
<function-name> <function-arg-name>* = <body>
```

In your case you have

```
<function-name> === joinList
<function-arg-name1> === a
```

So far so good, but then you have `+`, which Haskell won't parse as a name so it shows you a parse error. To fix it is simple though: remove the `+` and you'll be fine.

The bigger problem is that you have a `where` clause redefining all of your function argument names. If you want your function to work properly: You'll have to remove that `where` clause as well. The end result being

```
joinList a b = a ++ b
```

If you really wanted to be haskell-y you could write

```
joinList = (++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wil take a look at it!